# Why my widget doesn't notice when Screen turn on?

Tags: android, event-handling, android-widget

I developed an Android Widget like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In my widget

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        playNotification(context, true);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        playNotification(context, true);
    }
}

 static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
[...]
```

The updateAppWidget works perfectly. The notification instead doesn't work neither if the screen is turned on, nor if it is turned off.
What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" // not ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" // not ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

When you fix the intent filter in manifest, everything should work fine.

Comment: You're right, anyway, I edited the manifest from 
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON" />` to
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />` 
But **still doesn't work**.